# Checking and showing null value in MS Access Query

Tags: c#, sum, ms-access-2010, isnull

I'm trying to write an SQL query to show the sum of every category.
The problem is that I need the sum of every category and even if the sum is zero it should still display the results.

I am doing this by using the DAL layer, so through C# and I'm using an access 2010 database.

This is my current working query:

```
SELECT        SUM(f.bedrag) AS totaal, c.omschrijving, Limiet.maximumBedrag
FROM            ((Financien f INNER JOIN
                         Categorie c ON f.categorieId = c.id) INNER JOIN
                         Limiet ON f.limietId = Limiet.id)
WHERE        (f.inkomstOfUitgave = 1)
GROUP BY f.categorieId, c.omschrijving, Limiet.maximumBedrag
```

Now on top of the SUM function I also need to check for nulls, and if the sum of a category is 0 it should display 0. All results that are 0 now are filtered out, but I HAVE to see them.

Does anybody know how to fix it? I tried `IsNull()` and `NZ` but I couldn't get it working.
Here is a screenshot of the result of the query.
[image]

As you can see I get two results, but I should get 7 if the query would display the sum 0 results to.

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for also showing the 0 values was:
The answer was made by "drch", and I thank him a lot for this! :)

```
SUM(IIF(IsNULL(f.bedrag), 0, f.bedrag)) AS bedrag
```

There where a lot of other things wrong too, this is the full query:

```
SELECT        c.omschrijving as Omschrijving, SUM(IIF(IsNULL(f.bedrag), 0, f.bedrag)) AS bedrag, l.maximumBedrag as maximumBedrag
FROM            ((Categorie c LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Financien f ON f.categorieId = c.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Limiet l ON l.categorieId = c.id)
WHERE        (f.inkomstOfUitgave IS NULL) OR
                         (f.inkomstOfUitgave = 1)
GROUP BY c.id, f.categorieId, c.omschrijving, l.maximumBedrag
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about how to display Null as 0 in an Access query, consider this simple query.  It returns some rows with Null in the `SumOfbedrag` column.

```sql
SELECT y.categorieId, Sum(y.bedrag) AS SumOfbedrag
FROM YourTable AS y
GROUP BY y.categorieId
```

Using that SQL as a subquery, the containing query can transform Null to 0 with an `IIf()` expression.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.categorieId,
    IIf(sub.SumOfbedrag Is Null, 0, sub.SumOfbedrag) AS totaal
FROM
    (
        SELECT y.categorieId, Sum(y.bedrag) AS SumOfbedrag
        FROM YourTable AS y
        GROUP BY y.categorieId
    ) AS sub;
```

However, looking at your screenshot again makes me think the issue is actually that your query does not include rows with Null in the `totaal` column.  In that case, examine the underlying data before you aggregate it with `GROUP BY`.  See whether this query returns any rows ...

```sql
SELECT f.bedrag, c.omschrijving, Limiet.maximumBedrag
FROM
    (Financien f
    INNER JOIN Categorie c
    ON f.categorieId = c.id)
    INNER JOIN Limiet
    ON f.limietId = Limiet.id
WHERE
        f.inkomstOfUitgave = 1
    AND f.bedrag Is Null
```

If that query returns no rows, my best guess is that one or both of your joins should be changed from `INNER` to `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking "LEFT/RIGHT JOIN", too.

Comment: First of all, the subquery doesn't work, since "IS" isn't supported by the programma :(
Secondly, if I run your last query I indeed get NOTHING as a result! So I believe I'll need a left or right join then?
At this image you can see my db structure for the three tables I use, could you tell me how to code the join? I keep getting errors :/ And yes as a matter of fact everything that gives 0 as a sum should be displayed :) I need the other data for something else!
Table structure in Access: http://i.imgur.com/MWs4hm8.png

Comment: *"First of all, the subquery doesn't work, since "IS" isn't supported by the programma"* I created a table, then created and tested that query in Access 2007, and then copied the SQL text and pasted it into the answer. It is valid Access SQL

Comment: Yeah but the thing is I make the queries in C#, through a DAL layer.. and thats not the same SQL as the Access SQL so it seems :/
So I'm not allowed to use "IS"

Comment: Any other idea on how to fix thi HansUp? I'm pretty stuck here :/

Comment: From what you told us, it seems DAL rejects or mangles valid Access SQL.  So I don't see how I can help.  You need help from someone who knows DAL.